# How can I use Caps Lock to capitalize semi-colon?

Tags: xmodmap, capslock, remapping, xkb

I can't print colon using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. So, I thought it was better to use the colon just like we use the Caps Lock for capitalization of letters.

In other words: I want Caps Lock to work for all keys even for the semi-colon , so when the Caps is On I should get colon instead of semi-colon.

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: A better question would be "How do I fix my shift+; ?"

Comment: Yeah. I know that. But, It will be fun changing the way the keyboard works.

Comment: I added the method to do this mapping. The fun point made it irresistible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can check in `evdev.lst` the available XKB options

  ```
  $ grep caps: /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst
    caps:internal        Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
    caps:internal_nocancel Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift doesn't affect Caps Lock
    caps:shift           Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
    caps:shift_nocancel  Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift doesn't affect Caps Lock
    caps:capslock        Caps Lock toggles normal capitalization of alphabetic characters
    caps:numlock         Make Caps Lock an additional Num Lock
    caps:swapescape      Swap ESC and Caps Lock
    caps:escape          Make Caps Lock an additional ESC
    caps:backspace       Make Caps Lock an additional Backspace
    caps:super           Make Caps Lock an additional Super
    caps:hyper           Make Caps Lock an additional Hyper
    caps:shiftlock       Caps Lock toggles ShiftLock (affects all keys)
    caps:none            Caps Lock is disabled
    caps:ctrl_modifier   Make Caps Lock an additional Ctrl
  ```
- What it seems you are looking for `caps:shiftlock` but if you don't want a lock just as shift (hold+press other key) use `caps:shift` or `caps:shift_nocancel` instead.
- Install `dconf-editor` then go to:

  org → gnome → desktop → input-sources

  then add `caps:shiftlock` to `xkb-options`:

  ```
  ['caps:shiftlock']
  ```

  BTW, it's a comma separated list.

Comment: He wants to map shift to an entirely different key.

Comment: I want Caps Lock to work even for the semi-colon so when the Caps is On the colon works.

Comment: @NavaneethMohan, Nice to hear that but you could vote it up if you like it :). See http://askubuntu.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you got me interested. Here's how you do it:

1. Run `xev`.
2. Press the shift key, and some other key that you want to use in place of shift. Here's a sample output (truncated):

   `state 0x0, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
   state 0x0, keycode 77 (keysym 0xff7f, Num_Lock), same_screen YES,`
3. Remap keys:

   `xmodmap -e "keycode 77 = Shift_L"`

This will map the Num Lock key to Left Shift.